# Como preencher uma ListBox usando multi thread em VB .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, multithreading, vb.net

Em uma Windows Form Application tenho uma List Box que é preenchida a partir de uma lista de IP's. Funciona assim: existe um arquivo texto (`config.eep`) que contém uma série de IP's, ao pressionar um botão para atualizar a List Box, um *loop* é chamado enviando um ping para todos os IP's do arquivo. Somente os que respondem são inseridos na `ListBox`.

Esse é o código que atualiza a `ListBox` (`lstListaIpAtiv`):

```
Public Sub AtualizarListBox()
    'Atualiza a ListBox
    lstListaIpAtiv.Items.Clear()                                     'Limpa a ListBox
    Dim ping As Ping = New Ping
    Dim sLinhaAtual As String                                        'Linha corrente do arquivo de configuração
    Dim PingReply As PingReply
    Dim objLeitor As StreamReader
    Try
        objLeitor = File.OpenText(sCaminho)
    Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
        MsgBox("Arquivo de configuração não encontrado", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Aviso")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor                                     'Troca o cursor para o cursor de espera
    While objLeitor.Peek <> -1                                       'Looping nas Linhas, enquanto nao chegar ao fim do arquivo texto, ele não sai do loop
        sLinhaAtual = objLeitor.ReadLine()                           'Recupera a Linha do Arquivo e guarda na variavel do tipo string sLinhaAtual
        Try
            PingReply = ping.Send(sLinhaAtual)                       'Envia requisiçao de ping para IP da linha corrente
            If PingReply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then              'Verifica se houve resposta do IP em questão
                lstListaIpAtiv.Items.Add(sLinhaAtual)                'Grava a linha atual na list box caso essa responda ao Ping
            End If
        Catch ex As PingException
            Continue While
        End Try
    End While
    objLeitor.Close()                                                'Fecha o arquivo para escrita
    If (Not objLeitor Is Nothing) Then
        objLeitor.Dispose()
    End If
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow                                       'Retorna o cursor para o cursor normal
    lblNumMaqEnc.Text = lstListaIpAtiv.Items.Count()                'Conta quantos itens existem na ListBox e exibe na label
End Sub
```

O problema é que enquanto esse processo não termina, o resto da aplicação fica indisponível. Estou tentando resolver isso com a criação de uma outra *thread* para rodar esse processo separado enquanto a *thread* primária continua com a execução do resto da aplicação. Inseri o seguinte código no botão da que atualiza a `ListBox` (`btnAtualizar`):

```
 Dim AtualizaThread As New Thread(AddressOf AtualizarListBox)
 AtualizaThread.Start()
```

No entanto, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lstListaIpAtiv' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Como contornar isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alterações na interface só podem ser feitas pela própria thread que roda a interface.

A maneira mais fácil de garantir que isso aconteça é colocar o seguinte código no início do seu método:

```
Public Sub AtualizarListBox()
  If Me.InvokeRequired Then 
    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf AtualizarListBox)) 
  Else 
    ' seu código aqui
  End If 
End Sub
```

Com este código, você não estará mais alterando a `ListBox` diretamente, mas sim passando um *delegate* ao formulário, pedindo que ele rode seu código na thread dele, quando puder.

Porém, se o seu código for lento, ele vai travar a thread da interface até terminar a atualização, e a vantagem de ser uma thread separada vai se desfazer. Nesse caso, você tem dois caminhos pra resolver:

### 1. Separar um método menor só para fazer as atualizações na interface

Por exemplo, separa um método só para adicionar um item individual na ListBox, depois de já ter feito o ping e ter o resultado em mãos.

### 2. Não usar threads

Você não precisa necessariamente usar threads. Basta colocar, dentro do seu loop, uma chamada a `Application.DoEvents()`. Assim, você vai liberar a thread de UI para rodar os eventos pendentes (atualizar a tela, processar cliques, etc), e assim elimina a sensação de que a aplicação “congelou”.

Lembrando que um misto das duas alternativas também pode ser feito… Você pode usar threads, mantendo o seu algoritmo como já está, apenas usando o `Invoke` como coloquei no início da resposta, e adicionar um `Application.DoEvents()` no meio do seu loop para que a UI não congele.